# Can the review system be fixed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

I was just assigned the task of reviewing this [inappropriate answer](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/555175).

I immediately flagged the answer, and when I did so, the SE system issued a red notification indicating that the answer had already been deleted (which is a good thing).

At this point, I had just flagged the answer, and it had been deleted, so I wanted to press the `I'm Done` button.  But that button apparently becomes disabled in this situation.  Since no more action was needed (the answer was deleted), I pressed the `No Action Needed` button.  In response, the dreaded "STOP LOOK AND LISTEN" message appeared, banning me from performing any more reviews.

With about 1000 posts still waiting in the review queues, we should probably ask for the review system to be fixed so that people, like myself, who are willing to volunteer their time performing reviews can continue to do so (I'm a top 10 reviewer with thousands of reviews and over 500 helpful flags on this SE alone).

Anyways, the system banned me from reviews for a while, so I'm sorry I won't be able to help out and volunteer any time in the near future (unless someone can fix the issue).

Comment: Relevant: [Why did flagging as very low quality result in audit failure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281080)

Comment: " Yeah... something's wrong here. We're looking into it.  – Adam Lear♦ yesterday "

Comment: Relevant: [Failed known-bad audit after flagging because I'm Done was not enabled](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327580)

Comment: The long and short of @DavidPostill's links is, never ever click "No action needed" if action is needed -- that's what "Skip" is for

Comment: LOL... so when no action is needed (the post is already deleted), never ever click "No action needed".

Comment: Frankly, after about my 3rd 'stop look & listen' over a period of about a year I just gave up reviewing. I clear most of the queue daily on Ask Different where I've got 27k rep, but here I can do without the feeling that your every move is being scrutinised & no good turn goes unpunished.

Comment: @Tetsujin Don't you have review audits on Ask Different?

Comment: @DavidPostill - no, we're allowed to make mistakes; which are hopefully caught by multiple reviewers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that; this was completely broken for a few days, [but it should be all good now.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327580/failed-known-bad-audit-after-flagging-because-im-done-was-not-enabled/327896#327896)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Do you want to reinstate my ability to perform reviews?

Comment: I've lifted your review ban, since this bug made passing these audits difficult if not impossible. That said, next time you see something like this, please report it and then skip the review.

Comment: Thank you Shog.